# program in C read txt file = find min, max, avg

Tags: c

I need to write a program that opens a `txt` file and lists how many numbers are there (e.g. there are 25 numbers below) and then lists which number is the largest (max) and which is the smallest (min). The program then makes an average of these numbers.

So far,  my program only write how many numbers I got there. When I try to make the formula to the maximum, I simply stop and can't move.

Can you help me? How do I do that by reading the rows and evaluating the largest number?

````
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *input;

int open()

{
    if ((input = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  {
      printf("Error! opening file");

      return 0;
  }
}

int rows_reading ()
//Here i dont know what to do

{

input = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

}

void main ()
{
  char c;
  int linesCount = 0;
  float max, min;

  float a;
  float n;
  int count = 0;

  input = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

  while ((c = fgetc(input)) !=EOF)
  {
      if(c =='\n')
          linesCount++;

       } // this works

  while ((c = getc(input)) !=EOF)
       {
           for (a = 0; a <  count; a++){
               if (a > max)
               max = a;

               }

       } //this not work

  printf("In file is %d numerical values. Max value is %d"linesCount, max);

  return ;

}  ```
````

Comment: I don't see what count and the for loop are there for. No need to read the values several times to remember the max one! (nor the min, nor sum them to get the mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints only since it's classwork and you'll become a better developer if you nut it out yourself :-)

The idea is to scan all the numbers and remember which was the largest and smallest. For the average, you also need to accumulate a sum of all those number along with the count.

For example, consider the following pseudo-code:

```
def getMinMaxAvg(inputFile):
    set sum, count, smallest, largest all to zero
    set value to inputFile.getNumber()
    if none available, return error indication
    while true
        if count is zero or value is less than smallest:
            set smallest to value
        if count is zero or value is greater than largest:
            set largest to value
        add value to sum
        add one to count
        set value to inputFile.getNumber()
        if none available, return (smallest, largest, sum / count)
```

That's basically the flow you need. The first important thing here is the `inputFile.getNumber()`, the thing that gets your numbers. Your use of `fgetc` will input single characters, you'll probably want to use `fscanf` with the `"%d"` specifier, so you can input integers.

Just make sure you check the return value to ensure it worked okay:

```
int myInt; FILE *fileHandle = fopen(...);
if (fscanf(fileHandle, "%d", &myInt) != 1)
    // Did not scan properly, needs to be handled.
// Now, myInt contains your value.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Finally it is working :).

Answer (score 1):

You're reading your file character by character, which isn't a good way to read numbers. If the file contains the number "137" you will read '1', then '3', then '7'. It works for counting lines since you can just count the number of '\n' characters, which you're doing.

Does the file contain a list of numbers, one number per line? If so, you should use `fgets` to read the file one line at a time. Then you can use `atoi` to convert the string into an integer and look for the max, min, etc. One gotcha that you have to look out for us that `fgets` will store the `\n` in the string it returns, so you may need to remove it.

If your file contains numbers separated by spaces then you might consider `fscanf`, which may work too for lines...? Not really sure about that since it's been ages since I used `fscanf`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realise that i am reading file character by character. Stupid me. fscanf is working fantastic.